# Tests fail when using -f html for multiple scenario feature file

Tags: ruby, cucumber

When i try to format the results with -f html for a feature file with multiple scenarios I get the following error.

```
$ cucumber --expand -f html -o Output.html TestFeature1.feature 

class or module required (TypeError)
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/builder-3.0.0/lib/builder/xmlbase.rb:43:in `kind_of?'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/builder-3.0.0/lib/builder/xmlbase.rb:43:in `method_missing'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/../lib/cucumber/formatter/html.rb:411:in `set_scenario_color_failed'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/../lib/cucumber/formatter/html.rb:406:in `set_scenario_color'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/../lib/cucumber/formatter/html.rb:240:in `before_step_result'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:173:in `__send__'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:173:in `send_to_all'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:171:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:171:in `send_to_all'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:162:in `broadcast'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:104:in `visit_step_result'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/step_invocation.rb:43:in `visit_step_result'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/step_invocation.rb:39:in `accept'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:99:in `visit_step'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:163:in `broadcast'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:98:in `visit_step'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/step_collection.rb:15:in `accept'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/step_collection.rb:14:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/step_collection.rb:14:in `accept'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:93:in `visit_steps'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:163:in `broadcast'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:92:in `visit_steps'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/scenario.rb:55:in `accept'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:80:in `with_hooks'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:96:in `before_and_after'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:79:in `with_hooks'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:120:in `call'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:120:in `around'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/../lib/cucumber/language_support/language_methods.rb:9:in `around'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/../lib/cucumber/language_support/language_methods.rb:91:in `call'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/../lib/cucumber/language_support/language_methods.rb:91:in `execute_around'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/../lib/cucumber/language_support/language_methods.rb:8:in `around'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:119:in `around'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:117:in `call'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:117:in `around'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:91:in `around'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:78:in `with_hooks'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/scenario.rb:53:in `accept'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/scenario.rb:108:in `with_visitor'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/scenario.rb:47:in `accept'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:51:in `visit_feature_element'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:163:in `broadcast'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:50:in `visit_feature_element'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/feature.rb:43:in `accept'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/feature.rb:42:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/feature.rb:42:in `accept'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:20:in `visit_feature'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:163:in `broadcast'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:19:in `visit_feature'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/features.rb:29:in `accept'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/features.rb:17:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/features.rb:17:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/features.rb:28:in `accept'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:14:in `visit_features'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:163:in `broadcast'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:13:in `visit_features'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:46:in `run!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/../lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:43:in `execute!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/../lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:20:in `execute'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/cucumber:14
/usr/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
/usr/bin/cucumber:23
```

Cucumber version used: 1.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem :) I had an argument named Symbol which created the issue. Symbol is a variable used somewhere in the cucumber framework code.